# Ajax / JSON / PHP database data

Tags: php, ajax, json, database

I'm more of a designer but I need to grab some data from a database. I would be able to get what I need without problem using PHP but I'm creating a mobile app in Phonegap so can't use anything other than HTML, CSS or JS.

I've read that this can be done in a PHP file on the server, encoded to JSON and then grabbed in the HTML with Ajax.

Can anyone show me how do I do this, as **simply as possible please**?

Comment: Do you have anything so far? Do you know what your database schema is? Do you know how to connect to your database? Do you even know what type of database you have (MySQL, SQLServer, Postgres, etc)?\

Comment: "Anything other than HTML, CSS and JS" - basically that's the same that you have available in any web browser. PHP is server side technology. Internet is full of examples how to make AJAX call. Just make sure do you have jQuery available or not and search for jQuery example or pure JS one.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Hey. It's MySQL. I don't really have anything yet as I've just been trying out examples.

Comment: Thanks @MilanG will keep looking at examples

Comment: Look at my post bellow, I included all the flow you need, and the return value is in JSON. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript file**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "php/phpDb.model.php",
        data: {
          sataVariable: "here is some data send with GET method"
        },
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
      });
```

**php file (phpDb.model.php)**

```
// Connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "userName", "password", "database") 
    or die('{ "error" : true, "errorMessage" : "Cannot connect to database '.mysqli_error($con).'"}');

// Query
$sqlCalling = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCalling);
$rowCalling = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCalling);

mysqli_close($con);

//getting column_1 and column_2
$column_1  = $rowCalling['column_1'];
$column_2  = $rowCalling['column_2'];


// Return a JSON parseable array
    return array(
        "column_1" => $column_1 , 
        "column_2" => $column_2 ,
    );
```

This solution is very generic, you will most likely just replace the name of the tables and the name of column with what they actually are in your database.

Comment: you are welcome, the return object will be output on the console, you can access it through google chrome developer tools. on linux `CTRL` + `SHIFT`+`J`

Comment: don't forget to validate the answer and up vote if you find it meaningful. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example using jQuery:

```
//hello_world.js
$.ajax({
  url:'hello_world.php',
  type: 'POST'
  data: { 'var' : 'Hello World' }
}).done(function(response){
  alert(response); //Well now alert an json string based on your query..
});

//hello_world.php
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT blabla FROM table WHERE column = ?");
$STH->execute(array($_POST['var']));
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$resultQuery = $STH->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($resultQuery); //
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain this a little, as I really am new to this (sorry) So say in the php file I have connected to my database, selected the data i want with a query and i now have an array with the data in as JSON. What does this do in relation to that?

Comment: You should indicate in the ajax query that the return type is JSON

Comment: @JeanWilliamEyidi actually that isn't necessary